# Infinitiv + »zu« + Modalverb?

Tags: grammar, infinitive, modal-verb

> Glücklich, wieder Fußball **spielen zu können**!
>
> Ich freue mich, heute hier **sprechen zu dürfen**.
>
> Je länger man es schafft, die Figur **rennen zu lassen**, desto mehr Punkte erhält man.

Die Form mit *zu* und nur einem Infinitiv kenne ich schon. Die Bedeutungen dieser Sätze sind mir klar, aber ich kann keine Erklärung dazu finden. Ich habe festgestellt, dass das zweite Verb nach *zu* immer ein Modalverb oder *lassen* ist. Wie heißt diese Form und wo kann ich weitere Information finden?

Comment: Diese "Form" hat keine besonderen Namen. Man kann ja Sätze bilden wie _"Ich kann spielen."_ (Modalverb+Infinitiv) und _"Ich bin glücklich, wieder Fußball zu spielen."_ (zu+Infinitiv). Der Satz _"Ich bin glücklich, wieder Fußball spielen zu können."_ kombiniert einfach nur beide Konstruktionen, _spielen zu können_ ist aber keine eigene besondere Form.

Comment: Es wäre schön, dieser Kommentar als Antwort zu haben!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Diese Form hat meines Wissens keinen besonderen Namen.

Es gibt die Konstruktion **Modalverb + Infinitiv**, mit der man Sätze bildet wie:

> Ich kann spielen.

<sup>In *die Figur rennen zu lassen* liegt kein Modalverb(+Infinitiv) im konventionellen Sinne vor. "lassen" verlangt eine ähnliche Konstruktion, die [**AcI** (accusativus cum infinitivo)](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzbau/Hauptplan/aci.html) genannt wird. Das spielt für alles Weitere aber keine Rolle.</sup>

Und es gibt die Konstruktion **"zu" + Infinitiv** wie in der Infinitivgruppe im folgenden Satz:

> Ich bin glücklich, wieder Fußball zu spielen.

Dabei rückt der Infinitiv des vormals finiten Verbs (*Ich spiele.*) ans Ende der Infinitivgruppe.

Der Satz

> Ich bin glücklich, wieder Fußball spielen zu können.

kombiniert einfach nur die beiden Konstruktionen **Modalverb + Infinitiv** und **"zu" + Infinitiv**. Im Satz *Ich kann spielen* ist *können* das finite Verb, deshalb rückt es in der Infinitivgruppe ans Ende (*spielen zu können*).

---

Es gibt auch Verben, die vor einem Infinitiv ein *zu* verlangen; ein Beispielsatz für solch ein **Verb + "zu" + Infinitiv** ist:

> Ich habe nichts zu sagen. *(I'm not in a commanding position.)*

Eine Infinitivgruppe, die auf einer solchen Konstruktion basiert, braucht also zweimal das Wörtchen *zu*:

> Ich bin froh, nichts zu sagen zu haben. *(I'm glad not to be in a commanding position.)*

Das *zu* vor *sagen* gehört zur Konstruktion **(Verb +) "zu" + Infinitiv**; das *zu* vor *haben* gehört zur Infinitivgruppe. Wieder rückt das vormals finite Verb (*haben*) als Infinitiv ans Satzende.

Comment: Tolle Erklärung... wie viele "zu"s sind möglich? Ich habe das folgende Sats gefunden: „Er schafft es, dir immer wieder Geld für neue Vorhaben rauszuleiern, egal, wie oft du geschworen hast, nie wieder etwas mit ihm **zu tun zu haben zu wollen**. Ein Phänomen!“ :)

Comment: @Ubik: **zu tun zu haben zu wollen** enthält - wenn ich mich nicht total täusche - ein **zu** zu viel: Es heißt *Ich habe mit ihm zu tun*, also ist das **zu** vor **tun** richtig. Aber es heißt **Ich will haben**, also stimmt das **zu** vor **haben** nicht! Das **zu** vor **wollen** ist wiederum korrekt und kommt von der Infinitivgruppenkonstruktion. Aber wenn man ein anderes Verb statt **wollen** benutzt, das ein **zu** vor dem Infinitiv verlangt, dann sind drei (und mehr) **zu** s möglich: **zu tun zu haben zu scheinen**, beispielsweise.

Comment: Worte wie *zu tun* oder *zu sagen* als reguläre *zu*-infinitiv Konstruktion abzutun, empfinde ich nicht als richtig; Zudem ist *zu-sagen* polysem. Denn hässlich wird es, wenn *um etwas dazu zu tun* mit *dar zu tun, darlegen* verglichen wird. Ein anderes Beispiel fällt mir grad nicht ein.

Answer (score 3):

Das mit dem Modalverb stimmt nicht. Ob nach einem Verb überhaupt ein Infinitiv, und welcher, kommen kann, hängt schlicht vom Verb ab:

> Ich meine ihn zu hören.
>   Ich habe zu arbeiten
>   Ich muss arbeiten
>   Ich brauche nicht (zu) arbeiten
>   Ich gehe die Schwäne füttern.
>   *Ich muss zu arbeiten (Modalverb verlangt Infinitiv ohne zu)
>   *Ich esse Pizza gehen (essen kann keinen Infinitiv regieren)
>   *Ich meine ihn hören (meinen verlangt zu-Infinitiv)

Zu einem Deiner Beispiele:

> Ich freue mich
>  
>   Ich freue mich zu sprechen
>   Ich freue mich sprechen zu dürfen.

Dies ist dann der Weg, wie das Modalverb in der Konstruktion untergebracht wird.

Answer (score 0):

Zu diesem Thema habe ich in einem medizinischen Lehrbuch eine interessante Übung gesehen. Und ich konnte meinem Schüler es nicht erklären, obwohl ich natürlich übersetzen und Sätze bilden kann.[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34521)

Answer (score -3):

Laut Duden gibt es die Möglichkeit, eine Aufforderung auszudrücken durch: Modaler Infinitiv mit *zu* + *haben/sein.*

Beispiel:

> Die Tür ist zu öffnen!

Gleichbedeutend mit dem Imperativ:

> Öffne die Tür!

Comment: Das ist nur tangential eine Antwort auf die Frage.