# Infinitive with zu + modals in Nebensätzen?

Tags: subordinate-clause, infinitive, modals

This is one of the things that confuse me, what is the proper way of using infinitive with zu + modal verb in Nebensätzen?

I have see a sentence which had "zu haben können" at the end of second sentence? I assume this translates as "to be able to have" if so, does this context only apply to können?

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: see also here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/infinitiv-zu-modalverb

Comment: Mind you the position of the "zu" is wrong in your example. It must be "haben zu können".

Answer (score 3):

The scheme applies to all German modal verbs (wollen, sollen, mögen, können, dürfen, müssen) the same (and to quite some other verbs that can somewhat behave like modal verbs in this situation as well). Most of these verbs are verbs of perception and then a bunch of "miscellaneous" verbs I can't really classify.
Here is a non-exhaustive list of verbs that allow this construct:

> Er behauptete, nicht mehr laufen zu wollen

> Er behauptete, nicht mehr laufen zu sollen

> Er behauptete, nicht mehr laufen zu mögen

> Er behauptete, nicht mehr laufen zu können

> Er behauptete, nicht mehr laufen zu dürfen

> Er behauptete, nicht mehr laufen zu müssen

> Er stellte sich vor, ihn laufen zu sehen

> Sie genoss es, ihn atmen zu hören

> Er stellte sich vor, ihn reden zu lassen

> Er erlaubte ihr, tanzen zu gehen

> Sie fragte ihn, ob es ihm möglich sei, sie besuchen zu kommen

> Er begann damit, wieder laufen zu lernen

> Er dachte darüber nach, sie fechten zu lehren

Note (and don't confuse with) this is quite a bit different to a construct where we have a nominalized infinitive like in

> Es wird darum gebeten, das Rauchen zu unterlassen

Comment: lots of behauptet**et** that I'm to lazy to edit

Comment: @Olafant I ws about to say the same (about being lazy), but thanks.